# CSS Grid oveflow behaviour different in Firefox and Chrome

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, css-grid

I noticed different scrolling behaviour in Firefox and Chrome in the following snipped. In Firefox only the `.main` scrolls, in Chrome, the whole body scrolls. Am I doing something not to spec? Which browser is right? How can I get Chrome to behave like Firefox?

https://jsfiddle.net/Lgzb45np/

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template: 50px 1fr / 240px 1fr;
  height: 100%;
}

.header {
    grid-area: 1/1;
}
.sidebar {  
    grid-area: 2/1;
}
.main {  
  grid-area: 2/2;    
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}
.large-div{
  height: 800px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">Some Header Row</div>
  <div class="sidebar">A Sidebar</div>
  <div class="main">
  <div class="large-div">This is large</div>
  And Some More</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing the `height: 100%` from `.main` should work. You already define the height size of the `.main`column (1fr)

**CSS**

```
.main {  
grid-area: 2/2;    
overflow: auto;
}
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Lgzb45np/1/)